# How to stop JQuery loader after page has loaded?

Tags: jquery, html, css, django

I cannot get JQuery loader to disappear after loading web page. What types of issues usually cause the loader to not stop?

My web site is being built using Django framework and is on a local machine "localhost:8000". I have tried to clear Cache and Cookies but this does nothing. I have also tried setting a timeout but that does not seem to work either.

One concern I have is where to put the loader so I decided that putting it on the base.html was best. Could this be affecting it?

In my base.html file:

```
<div class="loader-wrapper">
<span class="loader"><span class="loader-inner"></span></span>
</div>
    <script>
       $(function(){
          $(window).on("load", function(){
              $(this).remove();
              });
          });
        });
    </script>
```

My CSS code:

```
.loader-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #242f3f;
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.loader {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  position: relative;
  border: 4px solid #Fff;
  animation: loader 2s infinite ease;
}
.loader-inner {
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  animation: loader-inner 2s infinite ease-in;
}
@keyframes loader {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg);}
  25% { transform: rotate(180deg);}
  50% { transform: rotate(180deg);}
  75% { transform: rotate(360deg);}
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
@keyframes loader-inner {
  0% { height: 0%;}
  25% { height: 0%;}
  50% { height: 100%;}
  75% { height: 100%;}
  100% { height: 0%;}
}
```

I expected the loader to spin until page loads then to fade out but all it does is continue to spin.

This code is re-used from another website. My goal is to get it working then examine the code to understand how it works so that I can create my own loader.

Thanks in advance for the help!

EDIT: When I put the JQuery code at the top of the html file it loads behind the blog app and continues to spin in the background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$(".loader-wrapper").remove();` instead of `$(this).remove();`

change your js to

```
<script>
 $(window).on('load',function(){
      $('.loader-wrapper').remove();
  });
 </script>
```

Comment: I found an error in the console that says `GET http://localhost:8000/jquery-2.1.4.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)` . I am assuming it is trying to access jquery on my local machine and not on the web. Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: You can include a link to a google hosted library for most common libraries. The one for your version of jquery would be: `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>`

You can see the whole list here: https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/

Comment: Thank you! I found this right as you posted it. There was a few issues. One was that I needed to use the Jquery src from googleapis. Secondly, the JQuery src needs to be posted in front of the code to be executed. Thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score 0):

At your html script part:

```
<script>

$(window).on("load", function(){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.loader-wrapper').remove()
    })
})
</script>
```

Comment: This did not work. When I remove the script the `<div class="loader-wrapper">` still executes. I assume this means that the JQuery code is not executing. Any thoughts on why this could be?